# Как заставить работать z-index в меню

Tags: html, css

Не могу заставить нормально работать z-index. Нужно скрыть sub-menu под главное.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="">Open</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>a</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 30;
  background-color: black;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
}

ul.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index:20;
  background-color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9z47bL5y/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
}

ul.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="">Open</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>a</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Оно, спасибо. Я так пробовал. Оказалась проблема в обще верстке